# Add place via Google Place API WEB Service with opening hours

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Is it possible to add new place with opening hours via Google Places API Web Service?

I can't find any information about it.

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place

Thank you in advance

Comment: The [Place Add](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place) has been deprecated on June 30, 2017 and will stop working on June 30, 2018. So you cannot use this method anymore. For further details please refer to the corresponding [geo blog post](https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2017/06/announcing-deprecation-of-place-add.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, no.  You can't provide opening hours in Add Place requests to the Google Places API.

Depending on what you need to do, you could try adding the place manually via https://google.com/maps (click "Send feedback" then "Add a missing place").

Comment: This sucks from Google!

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not possible. As you can see in this [document](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place#add-place), these are the only information that you can place in the body.

- `accuracy` — The accuracy of the location signal on which this request is based, expressed in meters.
- `address` (recommended, to improve chances of passing moderation) — The address of the place you wish to add. If a place has a well-formatted, human-readable address, it is more likely to pass the moderation process for inclusion in the Google Maps database.
- `language` — The language in which the place's name is being reported. See the [list of supported languages](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#using-google-maps-apis) and their codes. Note that we often update supported languages so this list may not be exhaustive.
- `location` (required) — The geographical location, specified as latitude and longitude values, of the place you want to add.
- `name` (required) — The full text name of the place. Limited to 255 characters.
- `phone_number` (recommended, to improve chances of passing moderation) — The phone number associated with the place. If a place has a well-formatted phone number, it is more likely to pass the moderation process for inclusion in the Google Maps database.
- `types` (required) — The category in which this place belongs. While types takes an array, only one type can currently be specified for a place. XML requests require a single `<type>` element. See the list of [supported types](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) for more information. If none of the supported types are a match for this place, you may specify other.

Hope this helps!